# How to check if any character in the character vector is inside any character in another list

Tags: r, dataframe, tibble

I have a rows of vectors in a single in the tibble dataframe and I have a set of filtered words. I want to filter the rows if the characters inside the vectors did not appear inside the filtered set. Eg. Based on the given table, only **row 1, 3 and 4** should be retained. I tried using the filter function but because vectors return True True, it seems to be filtered away and does not remain inside the data table. Is there any function I could use to check for words inside a list based on another list?

| tags |
| --- |
| c("hello", "hi") |
| c("blanks", "nothing") |
| c("thanks", "welcome") |
| hi |

```r
filtered_words <- c("hi","bye","thanks")
```

Comment: Can you share your `tags` tibble using `dput(tags)` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `any`:

```r
dataset[sapply(dataset$tags, \(x) any(x %in% filtered_words)), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `dplyr::filter()` function if you also use `rowwise()`:

```
filter(rowwise(df), any(filtered_words %in% tags))
```